# Load every 6 images after clicking on button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to add a Load More button to my website with only jQuery (no Ajax). My HTML images section structure is a list of elements mixed with some plugins like lightbox.

I tried many of jQuery tricks even this Fiddle, but no chance:

http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/

Here's my images code with the load more button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  
   <ul id="portfolio-container" class="portfolio-container real-gapped colored-mask masonry clearlist row portfolio-hover-effect">

     <li class="portfolio-item photo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x260" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-info font-second">
          <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">sweet nicky</h3>
          <div class="portfolio-item-detail">
             <p>apiente accusantium fugiat</p>
             <!-- LightBox Button -->
             <a href="https://vimeo.com/31240369" title="Image description" class="icon-magnifying-glass lightbox" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
             <!--/ End LightBox Button -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </li>
     
     <li class="portfolio-item photo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x260" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-info font-second">
          <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">sweet nicky</h3>
          <div class="portfolio-item-detail">
             <p>apiente accusantium fugiat</p>
             <!-- LightBox Button -->
             <a href="https://vimeo.com/31240369" title="Image description" class="icon-magnifying-glass lightbox" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
             <!--/ End LightBox Button -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </li>
     
     <li class="portfolio-item photo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x260" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-info font-second">
          <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">sweet nicky</h3>
          <div class="portfolio-item-detail">
             <p>apiente accusantium fugiat</p>
             <!-- LightBox Button -->
             <a href="https://vimeo.com/31240369" title="Image description" class="icon-magnifying-glass lightbox" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
             <!--/ End LightBox Button -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </li>
     
     <li class="portfolio-item photo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x260" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-info font-second">
          <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">sweet nicky</h3>
          <div class="portfolio-item-detail">
             <p>apiente accusantium fugiat</p>
             <!-- LightBox Button -->
             <a href="https://vimeo.com/31240369" title="Image description" class="icon-magnifying-glass lightbox" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
             <!--/ End LightBox Button -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </li>
     
     <li class="portfolio-item photo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x260" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-info font-second">
          <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">sweet nicky</h3>
          <div class="portfolio-item-detail">
             <p>apiente accusantium fugiat</p>
             <!-- LightBox Button -->
             <a href="https://vimeo.com/31240369" title="Image description" class="icon-magnifying-glass lightbox" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
             <!--/ End LightBox Button -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </li>
     
     <li class="portfolio-item photo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x260" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-info font-second">
          <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">sweet nicky</h3>
          <div class="portfolio-item-detail">
             <p>apiente accusantium fugiat</p>
             <!-- LightBox Button -->
             <a href="https://vimeo.com/31240369" title="Image description" class="icon-magnifying-glass lightbox" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
             <!--/ End LightBox Button -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </li>
     
     <li class="portfolio-item photo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x260" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-info font-second">
          <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">sweet nicky</h3>
          <div class="portfolio-item-detail">
             <p>apiente accusantium fugiat</p>
             <!-- LightBox Button -->
             <a href="https://vimeo.com/31240369" title="Image description" class="icon-magnifying-glass lightbox" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
             <!--/ End LightBox Button -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </li>

  </ul>
  
 <div class="small-section text-center">
    <a href="#" id="loadMore" class="btn btn-animated btn-split    btn-dark ripple-alone" data-text="Load more"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Load more&nbsp;..&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a>
 </div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Any help please !

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you know the urls to the additional images.  If you have them in an array, you could potentially do something conceptually like this:

```js
var moreImages = [
  "http://lorempixel.com/72/72/",
  "http://lorempixel.com/72/72/",
  "http://lorempixel.com/72/72/",
  "http://lorempixel.com/72/72/",
  "http://lorempixel.com/72/72/",
  "http://lorempixel.com/72/72/",
  "http://lorempixel.com/72/72/"
];

$("#more").on("click", function(){
  if (moreImages.length === 0) { return; }
  var target = $("#imageContainer");

  moreImages.splice(0,3).forEach(function(item){
    target.append("<li><img src=\"" + item + "\" /></li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="imageContainer">
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/72/72/" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/72/72/" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/72/72/" /></li>
</ul>

<button id="more">more</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```